# Topological spaces and metric spaces - notion of open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My lecture notes say that

> A topological space is an ordered pair $(X, \tau)$, where $X$ is a set and $\tau$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ that satisfy
>
> 1. $X$ and $\emptyset$ belong to $\tau$.
> 2. Any finite or infinite union of the elements of $\tau$ belong to $\tau$.
> 3. Any finite intersection of the elements of $\tau$ belong to $\tau$.
>
> **The elements of $\tau$ are called open sets** and $\tau$ is said to be a topology on $X$

I also know that for a metric space $(X,d)$, a set $M \subset X$ is open if for all $x \in M$, $\exists \varepsilon >0$ such that $\mathbb{B}_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset M$.

However, I am slightly confused about how the two definitions of openness match up...

Which is the more general version of openness? Is there a proof to show the more general idea of openness implies the other or to show they are equivalent?

Comment: The topological notion is the more general one. It covers all the possible cases of metric spaces (you can prove yourself that for a given metric space $(X, d)$, the collection of all possible $M$ described the way you did fulfills the criteria of a topology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you've highlighted in your box is the more general definition.  You can show that the open sets in a metric space satisfy the criteria for the general definition of "open set" (e.g. it isn't too hard to see that the union of open sets in a metric space is again an open set since unions will preserve the "wiggle room" about every point).

However, not every topology is [metrizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem).  A topology on a set $X$ is called *metrizable* whenever there exists a metric $d:(X,X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose open sets according to the "metric space" definition correspond with the open sets of the topology.  Easy examples of non-metrizable spaces are certainly to be had; for instance, consider the [trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) on any set containing more than one element, whose opens are simply $\emptyset$ and the whole space.

More interesting examples of non-metrizable spaces can be found by recognizing that metrizable spaces must be at least [Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space), though again one can find examples of non-metrizable Hausdorff spaces, such as the [lexicographic order topology on the unit square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square).  Determining whether a space is metrizable is, historically, a major problem in point-set topology, and [much work has been dedicated to finding relevant necessary and/or sufficient conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem#Metrization_theorems) with results such as [Urysohn's metrization theorem](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/notes/15-umt.pdf), the [Nagata–Smirnov metrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem), et al.

In summary, your two definitions are equivalent when the space is metrizable.  If it is not, then the second definition cannot even apply.

Answer (score 0):

It is an exercise to prove. For $x\in A\cap B$ where $A,B$ are two open set, there exists $\gamma, \delta>0$ such that $\mathbb{B}_\gamma(x)\subseteq A, \mathbb{B}_{\delta }(x)\subseteq B$,  then take $\epsilon=\min (\gamma, \delta)$, 
$\mathbb{B}_{\delta }(x)\subseteq A \cap B$. This prove $A\cap B$ is open. The argument of infinite union is trivial.

Moreover, there are a lot of axioms which can define topology, such as open sets axiom, closed sets axiom, neighborhood axiom, neighborhood basis axiom, and clossure axiom. see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space). They are determined each other.

And actually, metric space gives topology by neighborhood basis axiom.